# visual studio "publish android app" command not found

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Hello my friend I have problem in visual studio community 2015

Options " publish android app " Not found In list Tools --> Android

Can you Help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZMT9.png)

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you've set it to Release build

Comment: Why the downvote? If set to debug build you cannot publish it.

Comment: Because this isn't an answer by all means. It's more of a comment of "Did you ensure to do X so Y pops up". Where this actually wouldn't matter for the menu options even with the old tooling(< XVS 4.2). (It would simply just be grayed out). There's a note [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/visual-studio-xa-4.2.6-to-6.1/#Sign_the_APK) as well: